# How can I have a class as a parameter, and based on that add it into an arraylist of that class

Tags: java

I have many arraylists and each has a different class. How can I make a method that takes in what class arraylist you want to add to and an object of that class, then add the object to the arraylist of the given class?

I have tried making a `HashMap<Class<?>, ArrayList<?>>` called listMap and a method like this:

```
public <T> void add(T obj) {
    listMap.get(T).add(obj);
}
```

This doesn't work however because I can't say T.class, and passing in T to the Hashmap doesn't work.

Comment: Based on what you want to insert in your HashMap? all I see is the value, how can you deduct the key?

Comment: If B is a subclass of A and you call `obj.<A>add(new B())`, do you want the object added to the list for `A.class` or for `B.class`? The former is impossible due to type erasure, but it seems to be the desired behaviour according to your code because of trying to call `.get(T.class)` which, if it worked, would depend on the type parameter `T` rather than the actual parameter `obj`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have map, mapping a class instance to lists whose generic bound is that class, i.e. you might map, say, `String.class` to a `new ArrayList<String>()`.

That means the map's individual elements are different types. It is not possible to write generics to represent this. You must resort to raw types, code carefully, separate out the unsafe calls to small methods, and stick a `@SuppressWarnings` on those.

```
private final Map<Class<?>, List<?>> map;
public <T> void add(T obj) {
    Class c = obj.getClass(); // yeah, raw.
    map.computeIfAbsent(c, x -> new ArrayList()).add(obj); // raw again.
}

public <T> T getFirst(Class<T> type) {
    List list = map.getOrDefault(type, List.of());
    return (T) (list.isEmpty() ? null : list.get(0));
}
```

all these ops get you unsafe warnings but nevertheless, you won't get 'heap corruption' (where you end up with classcastexceptions in places where there are no visible casts, due to problems caused by ignoring generics warnings).

NB: As a general rule, if you use `Class<T>` like this, you're messing up. For example, if you 'add' an integer at some point (which is a Number, because Integer extends Number), and then later call 'get', passing Number.class, you don't get the integer back. An anonymous extension to anything technically is a different class, so that doesn't work either. You also cannot convey generics in class literals, so there's no way to have the notion 'the class object representing `List<String>`' (there is only `List.class`, you cannot generics it). There are various alternatives, and without knowing your precise situation it is hard to recommend the proper solution here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the type of `T obj`, calling `obj.getClass()` will return a `Class` object that represents the class `T`.

A simple implementation looks like this:

```
public <T> void add(T obj) {
    Class c = obj.getClass();

    if (listMap.containsKey(c)) {
        listMap.get(c).add(obj);
    } else {
        listMap.put(c, new ArrayList<T>().add(obj));
    }
}
```

In this case, your map would look like:

```
Map<Class, List> listMap = ...
```

Unfortunately, since the types are only provided at runtime, you will not get compile-time type-checking on any of the contents of `listMap`. E.g. `listMap.get(someClass).get(0)` will return an `Object`.

Comment: This doesn't work because `Arrays.asList` returns a list where `add` throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`; you need to use `new ArrayList<T>()`. Or more succintly in Java 8+, `listMap.computeIfAbsent(c, key -> new ArrayList<T>()).add(obj);`